# Checking if an input is in sql alchemy data-type format

Tags: python, sql, excel, sqlalchemy

So I'm parsing information from an excel sheet and am running into some data-type issues.

There are different fields, some are dates and some are strings, etc. The problem is some people are idiots and are inputting things incorrectly. So a date field might just be 'na' or something like that. I am trying to do a condition where if it's not the correct format, replace it with None.

so in psuedo-code

```
if not( expiration_date is Date.format):
       expiration_date = None
```

However I can't find anything online that can help me. Is there any efficient way of doing this?

Comment: You'll want to use `type(expiration_date)` , and if the variable is not a date/time, replace it with none.

Comment: for person in people: person=person.astype('not idiot')?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case you wanted the code, here you go:

```
import datetime

expiration_date=datetime.datetime.now()

if  type(expiration_date) != datetime.datetime:
    expiration_date = None
```

Comment: Thanks so much! didn't realize you could do something like that